# Find the sum of all the minimum differences of pairs in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sum, difference

I want to find the differences between all closest-neigbour pairs and sum them, given the input array is even-length.

I have this code right now but it only gives the minimum difference of one pair.
How do I go about to achieve this? So take out the pairs who have already been summed and calculate with the rest of the pairs.

```
 var lowestDiff = Infinity;
arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
    lowestDiff = Math.min(lowestDiff, Math.abs(arr[i] - arr[i + 1]));
}
   console.log(lowestDiff);
```

So for example if the input is: [6,2,3,6], output would be: 1 because 6 pairs with 6 and 2 pairs with 3

So essentially i want to pair an element with another element which is closest to them, and get that difference. And sum them.

Comment: Please provide some more examples as the question is not clear.

Comment: Assume the inputs are always even @YevgenGorbunkov

Comment: @saurabhsisodia is it now clearer?

Comment: @Sven.hig no 1 because 2 pairs up with his closest neighbour - 3.

Comment: Considering, you say *'...all possible pairs...'* shouldn't your example result into 13 (6-2 + 2-3 + 6-3 + 6-3 + 6-2 + 6-6) ?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov no because an element can only be in one pair - his closest neighbour

Comment: Then it seems to contradict *'all possible'*-condition. So it is closest (in terms of position in sorted copy) only?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov youre right - i updated the title

Comment: "closest" means minimum difference??

Comment: @saurabhsisodia yes, so compare an element with the others and take the one with the least difference

Comment: So for `[1,4,5,9]` the expected result would be 7 (4-1 + 9-5)? Even though the pair 4/5 is much closer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you need to find the sum of the minimum difference pairs from an even length array. One thing to  **note:**  here is that-:  **After sorting the given array closest pairs will be adjacent to each other**
So, I think below code should work

```js
function min_difference(arr)
{
       arr.sort(function(a, b) {
          return a - b;
                });
       let ans=0;
       for (let i=1;i<arr.length;i+=2)
      {
          ans+=(arr[i]-arr[i-1]);
      }
       return ans;
}
var arr=[2,2,2,2];
console.log(min_difference(arr));
```

Comment: The explanation is good, but [the sorting does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1063007/1048572) and I'd recommend a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop.

Comment: @Bergi Thank You very much. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @saurabhsisodia : `Math.abs()` in above case seems to do only to things: slow down your code and make it more verbose. As long as your items are sorted in ascending order, the difference between them will be positive (or 0) anyways. Also, I would recommend to wrap that code block into function which would return `ans` rather than `console.log()` it. You may consider to turn your code into live-snippet, as well.

Comment: @saurabhsisodia : you're supposed to do rather something, like `function min_difference(arr){..`, aren't you?